# Linux application file path location in shared folder [Java application]

Tags: linux, filepath

I have created a Java application that loads file server paths from filePath.properties file.

When I run this application from a Linux machine, the file is written in to the bin folder in Jboss in my machine and reads and writes the file in that created folder instead of writing it to the shared folder in another Linux machine.

For example, I have given the file path location to be loaded as "smb://s141/share/" in filePath.properties [smb://s141/share/ is the shared location]

But instead of creating a file in the above location, it is created in "/programs/jboss/bin/smb:/s141/share/" of my machine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that kind of network without an appropriate import. Take a look at Java JCIFS http://sanjaal.com/java/tag/java-cifs-networking-protocol-usage-example/